# SQL - несколько условий для одного столбца, вывод в разные столбцы

Tags: sql

Есть два запроса, которые нужно объединить в один
`` SELECT otdel, COUNT(id_task )as c1 FROM `task` WHERE status_task=0 GROUP BY otdel ORDER BY otdel `` 
и
`` SELECT otdel, COUNT(id_task )as c2 FROM `task` WHERE status_task=2 GROUP BY otdel ORDER BY otdel ``

В результате должна получиться таблица:

| otdel | c1 | c2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | Null |
| 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | Null | 3 |

Вместо Null можно 0.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Стандартный прием «Разворот CASE'ом»

```
SELECT
  otdel,
  SUM(CASE WHEN status_task=0 THEN 1 END) AS c1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN status_task=2 THEN 1 END) AS c2
FROM `task`
GROUP BY otdel
ORDER BY otdel
```

В некоторых СУБД для этого есть отдельная команда `PIVOT`

Comment: *Стандартный прием «Разворот CASE'ом»* Лучше называть его по науке - "Условное агрегирование". Которое классически делается через COUNT: `COUNT(CASE WHEN status_task=1 THEN 1 END)`, что позволяет избежать NULL в выходном потоке.

Comment: @Akina, согласен. Но этот вопрос поставлен так, что null предпочтительнее нуля

Answer (score 0):

Вот такое решение получилось, всем спасибо!

```
SELECT otdel,
    COUNT(CASE
            WHEN status_task = 0
                THEN status_task
            ELSE NULL
            END) as status0,
    COUNT(CASE
            WHEN status_task = 2 
                THEN status_task
            ELSE NULL
            END) as status2
FROM `task`
GROUP BY otdel
ORDER By otdel
```

Comment: Во-первых, `ELSE NULL` не нужен. `CASE` и так вернет NULL, если не выполнено ни одно условие и нет `ELSE`. Во-вторых, для полного соответствия исходному запросу должно быть `THEN id_task`, а не `THEN status_task`. Разница будет если `id_task` может быть NULL при заполненном `status_task`.